# Name of fantasy novel about flying ships

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember too many details from this book I read a few years ago. It had the following elements:

- In English, not a translation
- Flying ships (large wooden tall ships), I think through magic, but it may have been balloons or a combination. They definitely had sails for lateral propulsion.
- A rune/glyph based magic system
- A pistol duel, one of the characters cheats by swapping the guns. It is concluded by someone shooting the other in the ear on purpose.
- A mute character (or a character who couldn't communicate for some reason)
- A character who is a monk
- May have involved dragons, but they did not factor heavily into the plot if it did

If I recall correctly, the book was the first in a series, and the others had yet to be written, I'm asking because maybe the second or even third book has been written by now.

Comment: How many years ago is " afew years ago", and when would the book itself would have been published? Any recollection of the cover? Was it in English, was it a translation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Aeronaut%27s_Windlass matches on about half the points... there are flying ships, a magic system, pistols, and monks. Not certain if they had a mute character. And, well, one entry released so far...

Comment: Were there dragons?  A yes or no answer would probably split the range of possibilities in half. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots no I'm almost certain that isn't it (based on the plot on Wikipedia) but thank you

Comment: @DavidW it hadn't occurred to me until you said that, but I think yes, however they aren't a large part of the plot? Honestly not sure

Comment: @Jenayah English, not a translation, really not sure how many years ago, between five and ten. Because the series was in progress, I can't imagine it was published too long before that. Definitely 2000s onward. The cover was an illustration in muted tones, it had ropes and a storm, probably ships, but I can't really remember well enough to properly describe it.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly **The Ill-Made Mute** (The Bitterbynde Book 1) by Cecilia Dart-Thornton, published 2001.

No promises on this one, I read halfway through about 6 months ago and was distracted before finishing.  If this is the correct book though then you are in luck regarding sequels, as *The Lady of the Sorrows* and *The Battle of Evernight* were both published in 2002.  If I have time I will read further and update this answer.

- English language - check, the author is Australian and no indication of translation.
- Flying wooden sailing ships - yes, *windships* float through use of a magical metal *sildron*, with *andalum* as a metal that neutralises the lifting force.
- rune / glyph magic system - more or less, there is *gramarye* that wizards use and folk remedies for the peasants to drive away Unseelie beings.
- pistol duel - not that I have read yet.
- a mute character - definitely, the main protagonist is *apparently* a mute boy, as a result of injuries sustained from a long fall in the first few pages.
- a character who is a monk - not yet, although the cover illustration shows a figure who looks to be in a monk's robes.
- may have involved dragons - not that I have read yet, but there are *eotaurs*, winged Skyhorses with *sildron* horseshooes.

Comment: Is there an obvious reason why the title is an illusion to part three of *The Once and Future King*:  *The Ill-Made Knight* (who is Lancelot)?

Comment: The [covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?21440) fit the "muted tones" description, but I don't know about "ropes and a storm."